# LEFT JOIN query is so slow it times out

Tags: mysql

The below query is taking so long to run that eventually it just times out.  I looked at the EXPLAIN plan and it seems that it's not using the indices of one of my tables so I assume that has something to do with it though I'm not sure why that's happening.  Here's the query:

```
SELECT documentID
     , coID
     , suiteID
     , leaseID
     , assetID
     , vendorID
     , feed_documents.did
     , document_links.doid
  FROM feed_documents
  LEFT 
  JOIN document_links 
    ON feed_documents.did = document_links.doid
 WHERE doid IS NULL
 LIMIT 0, 75000
```

And here's the results of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table           type  possible_keys key   key_len ref                               rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      feed_documents  ALL   NULL          NULL  NULL    119363                            NULL    NULL
1   SIMPLE      document_links  ref   doid          doid  4       rladmin_rlhpsi.feed_documents.did 12      Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

The feed_documents table has indexes on all the select/join columns, and document_links has indexes on all columns.  Can someone see what I've done wrong here?

UPDATE: table definitions, by request.

```
CREATE TABLE `feed_documents` (
 `documentID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `documentTitle` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `documentFileName` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `documentDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `documentArchived` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `documentTypeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `suiteID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `leaseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `assetID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `vendorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`documentID`),
 KEY `coID` (`coID`),
 KEY `suiteID` (`suiteID`),
 KEY `leaseID` (`leaseID`),
 KEY `assetID` (`assetID`),
 KEY `vendorID` (`vendorID`),
 KEY `did` (`did`),
 KEY `documentTypeID` (`documentTypeID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `document_links` (
 `dlid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `daid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Dataset ID',
 `linkid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID value of linked item',
 `doid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Document ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`dlid`),
 KEY `daid` (`daid`),
 KEY `linkid` (`linkid`),
 KEY `doid` (`doid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=148767 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please show the output of `show create table feed_documents;` and `show create table document_links;`.

Comment: The `explain` looks quite reasonable -- doing an index lookup on the second table.  The field `document_links.doid` is unnecessary in the `select`, but that is probably not a problem.  Perhaps some other process has locks on the table, affecting your query performance.

Comment: What about primary, unique and indexes ?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Added in the table details - I don't think there are other locks going on as this application hasn't rolled out to many users and this particular area doesn't get much activity yet.  If I LIMIT 0, 2000 it completes in about 30-40 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Just needed a different approach on the query:

```
SELECT documentID, coID, suiteID, leaseID, assetID, vendorID, feed_documents.did
FROM feed_documents
WHERE feed_documents.did NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT feed_documents.did
    FROM feed_documents
    JOIN document_links ON feed_documents.did = document_links.doid )
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you want `doid` to be `NULL` and `feed_documents.did = document_links.doid` in your query.

As far as I understand this means `join` all rows where `feed_documents.did = null` to all rows where `document_links.doid`.
This is many to many relation and it is no surprise that your query is slow especially if you have many rows in feed_documents with `did = null` and many rows in  document_links with `doid = null`.

If there are `n` matching rows in first table and `m` matching rows in second table your resultset will contain `n*m` rows which could be huge depending on your data.

Either way, why do you need 75000 rows at once?

PS
Leave alone your query may be slow If it times out maybe one or both of the tables are locked by another query.